# TeXstudio readAllStandardOutputStr seems not to work

Tags: macros, texstudio, scripts, javascript

I try to insert automatic timestamps into a LaTeX file, to get id's for some items
On a windows machine I have got the following macro (JavaScript):

```
    %SCRIPT
    var res=system("c:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe -c '/bin/date +%%s'");
    var timestamp=res.readAllStandardOutputStr();
    res.waitForFinished();
    editor.write(timestamp);
```

I can see the correct result (a long number indicating seconds) appear on the messages screen in TeXStudio:

```
    Prozess gestartet: c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c '/bin/date +%s'
    1392656846
    Prozess endete normal
```

Nothing spectacular. I tested the exit code, which was OK as well. But it seems not to gather stdout using `readAllStandardOutputStr()` as I see nothing to appear in my file. `editor.write` seems to work according to tests I tried. Putting `readAllStandardOutputStr()` after `waitForFinished()` didn't help either.
Help ot hint appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the standard output is empty. Likely it get's read out internally for the message panel before your call (This would be a bug, or at least a misleading description in the documentation). In your case, you can use this code:

```
%SCRIPT
var res=system("texdoc --version");
res.standardOutputRead.connect( function(output) {
    editor.write(output);
});
res.waitForFinished();
```